# Error: Failed to install provider while installing AWS provider

Tags: windows, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here's my provider block

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the full error message

```
Error while installing hashicorp/aws v4.12.1: chmod
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws/4.12.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.12.1_x5: operation not permitted
```

This is my first time trying to run Terraform using WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) and I've never received this error before when using powershell. Couldn't find any answers or fixes online.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue recently. WSL restart helped. Win + R →

```
wsl --shutdown
```